# Get tables names of my database and their columns name

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have to get all tables names of my database, and I have to get their columns name.
Please help me :)

EDIT : I have to use "Entities to SQL" from Entity framework. I can also use Entity SQL.

Comment: Hi, and very welcome to SO! What have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the information schema and native SQL select statements for this:

For tables:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

For columns:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   ORDER BY table_catalog,table_schema,table_name,ordinal_position
```

If you also need information if the column is an identity column, try this:

```
SELECT *,columnproperty(object_id(quotename(TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.'+quotename(TABLE_NAME)),
   COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') AS IS_IDENTITY FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   ORDER BY table_catalog,table_schema,table_name,ordinal_position
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply - But I forgot to say I have to do that with "Linq to Entities".